# What's the ruling on poetry?

Tags: shirk, poetry

Is it halal for a writer to write phrases like "Life blesses us with opportunities," "Time changes everyone completely," or "Life tests everyone." Is one commiting shirk if one uses these phrases while talking or writing poetry?

Comment: Oh my God. Please everyone on this website stop saying on simple stuff like this totally unrelated to the Oneness of God and His worship "is this shirk". No it's not shirk. It would be if you were writing on some imaginary god etc.

Answer (score 0):

"life" and "time" exist, they are not imaginary deities. It is definitely not shirk.

It is also allowed to say such "kitchen wisdom" without direct reference to God who is the source of life or the ruler over time.